# How can I follow a twitter user using Twitter4j framework?

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I need my Java Twitter application to be able to follow a user in twitter. When I pass it the  user ID as a string, the application follow it automatically. I couldn't find the method that can do that in Twitter4j.

Comment: You should delete this question, or write your own answer since you solved it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No need for id. It will work with username as well.

```
mTwitter.createFriendship("dj")
```

Answer (score 7):

Problem solved ,you can follow a user using [`twitter.createFriendship("twitter id");`](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/api/FriendsFollowersResources.html#createFriendship%28java.lang.String%29) method

Answer (score 0):

The following configuration will do it:

```
ConfigurationBuilder cb =new ConfigurationBuilder();
        cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
          .setOAuthConsumerKey("******")
          .setOAuthConsumerSecret("******")
          .setOAuthAccessToken("*******")
          .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("********");

        //In case of proxy 
        //cb.setHttpProxyHost("******").setHttpProxyPort(8080);


        TwitterFactory twitterFactory=new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
        Twitter twitter=twitterFactory.getInstance();

         twitter.createFriendship("twitter id");
```